# sqlalchemy async with_entities do not work (object has no attribute 'with_entities')

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

In sync sqlalchemy i could apply `with_entities` to rewrite some keys  and limit fields to return

And it looks like below

```
query = session.query(Model)
query = query.with_entities(Model.id.label('new_id'))
```

Now i use async sqlalchemy  and i try to apply the same logic (with_entities). But it doesn't work.

Raise an Error

```
Exception Rollback 'ChunkedIteratorResult' object has no attribute 'with_entities'
```

```
 query = select(User).offset(offset).limit(limit)
        query = await session.execute(query)
        query = query.with_entities(
            User.id.label('new_id') # how to achieve it? 
        )
        users = query.fetchall()
```

Comment: You've reassigned `query` to be the result of executing the query, so it's no longer a query object.

Comment: @snakecharmerb if i continue query without execution it cause Exception 'Select' object has no attribute 'with_entities'

Comment: Does [with_only_columns](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.Select.with_only_columns) do what you want?

Comment: @snakecharmerb no (if use with_entities) your could compute some func (func.count for example) but in case with_only_columns - you can't